# Run and stop my_function() in thread_1 by pressing buttons in Beeware Toga app running in the main thread

Tags: python, multithreading, beeware

I am trying to find a way to run and stop a function my_function() that should run continuously in thread_1 by pressing buttons in my Beeware Toga app that runs in the main thread with several buttons.
The main issue is that when the my_function() is running it blocks the Beeware Toga GUI and cannot be stopped. I could not find a way to do it, and I run out of ideas.
Any suggestion or hint would be much appreciated

**UPDATE:** I found why the Toga GUI got stuck. It was caused by a time competition between the two threads. Setting time.sleep(0.1) as the first statement in my_function() solved the problem

Comment: I see you've solved your problem by adding a sleep, but it would be faster and more reliable to use one of the [thread synchronization](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html) APIs like `Condition` or `RLock`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your suggestion and the comprehensive reference. I tried using RLock which is of simple use, and seems to work well for me. It feels more dependable and general than trying to guess a sleep period, and i will adopt it.