# Use of RLock in Beeware Toga app: GUI blocked when running a background thread

Tags: python, multithreading, beeware

I'm trying to develop a simple application where there is a background task that I want to turn on and off with a switch button.
That background task will show once per second a random number on a GUI label.

My current code is:

```py
import toga
from toga.style import Pack
from toga.style.pack import COLUMN, ROW
import time, threading, random

class MainApp(toga.App):
    def startup(self):
        main_box = toga.Box(style=Pack(direction=COLUMN))
        self.value = toga.Label("", style=Pack(flex=1))
        button_1 = toga.Button(
            "start/stop", on_press=self.background, style=Pack(padding=5)
        )
        main_box.add(self.value)
        main_box.add(button_1)
        self.main_window = toga.MainWindow(title=self.formal_name)
        self.main_window.content = main_box
        self.main_window.show()

        self.ev = threading.Event()
        self.lock = threading.RLock()

    def background(self, widget):
        if self.ev.is_set():
            self.ev.clear()
        else:
            self.ev.set()
            th = threading.Thread(target=self.print_numbers)
            th.start()

    def print_numbers(self):
        # time.sleep(0.1)
        while self.ev.is_set():
            value = random.randint(0, 100)
            # with self.lock:
            self.value.text = value
            time.sleep(1)

def main():
    return MainApp("Application", "com.example")
```

However when I start the application and press the button to start the background task, the application freeze.
As reported in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77210346/run-and-stop-my-function-in-thread-1-by-pressing-buttons-in-beeware-toga-app-r), it is caused by a time competition between the two threads (background and main), and setting `time.sleep(0.1)`, as the user report, solve the problem (temporarely).
As suggested in the comments of the same question, I tried to implement the thread synchronization APIs `RLock`, but when I run the application with the lock (the line commented in my code) it doesn't show anything

Am I missing something? Is that the right implementation of `RLock`? The is some workaround for this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> it is caused by a time competition between the two threads (background and main)

I don't think so, because the background thread is hardly doing any work. It's more likely to be caused by accessing the GUI on a background thread, which is not reliable on Toga or most other GUI toolkits.

In this simple example, you can turn your background task into an async function and avoid multi-threading completely:

```py
import asyncio
...

        self.ev = asyncio.Event()

    def background(self, widget):
        if self.ev.is_set():
            self.ev.clear()
        else:
            self.ev.set()
            # self.loop requires Toga 0.4 or later.
            self.loop.create_task(self.print_numbers())

    async def print_numbers(self):
        while self.ev.is_set():
            value = random.randint(0, 100)
            self.value.text = value
            await asyncio.sleep(1)
```

Or if you need the background task to do some CPU-intensive work, this can easily be moved to a separate thread using `run_in_executor`:

```py
    async def print_numbers(self):
        while self.ev.is_set():
            value = await self.loop.run_in_executor(
                None, some_slow_function, arg1, arg2, ...
            )
            self.value.text = value
```